# sort an array of strings in alphabetical in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

i have a linked list of srtings that i need to sort in alphabetical order 
and i am tryping to copy the strings to an array and then sort and print them in alphabetical order

```
void DisplayAll(k *l,p *p)
{
int i,j;
p *temp;
temp = malloc(l->num*sizeof *temp);
for (i = 0; i < l->num; i++)
{
    strcpy_s(temp[i].name, 20, p->name);
    p = p->next;
    i++;
}
for (i = 0; i < l->num - 1; i++){
    for (j = i + 1; j< l->num; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(temp[i].name, temp[j].name) > 0)
        {
            strcpy_s(temp->name,20, temp[i].name);
            strcpy_s(temp->name[i],20, temp[j].name);
            strcpy_s(temp->name[j],20, temp->name);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < l->num-1; i++){
    printf("%s\n", temp[i].name);
}
}
```

this is the k struct and the p stuct

```
typedef struct p
{
char name[20];
struct p* next;
}p;

 typedef struct k
   {
    int num;
    p *head;
   }k;
```

and i getting an Error evey time i run it

Comment: `and i getting an Error`... What is it?

Comment: What is this -`l->numofprod` ? there is no member in any structure with that name .

Comment: I hope your actual `typedef`'s are using names that are more, erm, sane than `p` and `k`

Comment: it num,i fixd that
there are it just a quick example

Comment: `p *p`  use another name for variable name --> `p *np`. Also 
There is no `}` for `if{ }`

Comment: editing the question/code substantially makes answers obsolete or even "wrong" like mine, that ha sno context any more for the late arriving reader of this post. NEVER do this

Comment: @PeterMiehle: Rolled back the last edit because most of the issues that could've been causing this vague _"error"_ were edited out.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of problems with your code:

***First off***: This doesn't look right at all:

```
strcpy_s(temp->name,20, temp[i].name);
strcpy_s(temp->name[i],20, temp[j].name);
strcpy_s(temp->name[j],20, temp->name);
```

according to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx):

```
errno_t strcpy_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource 
);
```

The first and last arguments are expected to be of the type `char*`. You've defined `struct p .name` as `char[20]`, so `temp->name[i]` will be of type `char`.

I guess you're actually trying to do something like this:

```
//get struct p at offset i in temp, access member "name"
strcpy_s(temp[i].name, 20, temp[j].name);
```

***Secondly***: You're allocating memory for `temp`, but you fail to `free` it once you're done (ie when your function returns). You have, in other words, a memory leak. Sure, once your program exits, the memory is almost certainly going to be freed, but if you're writing programs that have to run for extended periods of time, and functions like this are getting called several times over, your memory consumption will gradually increase, and you don't want that to happen. In short, after your last loop (where you print everything out), add this:

```
free(temp);
```

### Edit

You've added the `free` call now, and -correctly- wrap it in an `if (temp)`. However: if `malloc` had returned a `NULL` pointer, don't you think you should've cought that at the beginning of the function?

```
temp = malloc(l->num * sizeof *temp);
if (!temp)
    return;//or return int to indicate error or or exit EXIT_FAILURE; or something
```

There's no reason for you to reach the point where you `free(temp)` without having successfully allocated the memory.

***Third***: As @Bluepixy pointed out in his comment, there's a syntax error, too: the `if (strcmp(temp[i].name, temp[j].name) > 0)` branch is never closed properly: you're missing a closing bracket after the third `strcpy_s` call.

***Lastly***, you're allocating enough memory to accomodate `l->num` structs. You initialize them in such a way that every other struct will be assigned the `name` member of the next `struct p` in a list. You're not really making sure that `p->next` isn't a null pointer. This could cause problems (dereferencing a null pointer). So change the first loop into something like this:

```
int l_num  = l->num;//you'll see why
for (i = 0; i < l_num; i+=2)//increment twice if you want/need to
{
    strcpy_s(temp[i].name, 20, p->name);
    p = p->next;
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        l_num = i+1;//this is as far as we ought to go in the subsequent loops
        break;//or handle error in some way
    }
}
```

After this, replace all your `;i < l->num;` conditions in your loops with `i < l_num` or `j < l_num` to avoid using uninitialized string values.

***Just a final tip***: If you're not working on anything too time critical, it might be useful to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, especially when dealing with strings, or use `memset(temp[i]->name, 0, 20);` to ensure all `char[]` members are indeed empty strings.
If you find yourself using a lot of `str*` functions (`strncat`, `strncpy` and the like), even something as simple as `temp[i]->name[0] = '\0';` can make life a lot easier.